# Why will anyone still play SatoshiDice?

Tags: satoshidice

There seems to be a new [SatoshiDice](http://legacy.satoshidice.com/) clone called [BetCoinDice](http://www.betcoindice.tm/).

Everything is the same, except the expected return for the player is higher since the house percent is lower.

If this is the case, is it true that it doesn't make sense to use SatoshiDice any more?

Comment: Some people think BetCoin is not a honest business http://bitcoinmagazine.com/7659/betcoin-tm-allegedly-fraudulent-activity/

Comment: @LocalBitcoins, If you are the in charge of localbitcoins.com, take a look at this: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/16579/what-does-this-phishing-website-compromise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gamblers will pay a premium to play on a trusted, reputable site that has a long history of not defrauding its customers.

As noted by LocalBitcoins, Betcoin is accused of shady behavior, including lying about their trademark, failing to correctly use a provably fair system, playing on their own site to inflate volume, and DDoSing competitors. Source: http://bitcoinmagazine.com/7659/betcoin-tm-allegedly-fraudulent-activity/